# How to mail merge in a protected document or simular

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm trying to do a mail merge with protected templates which Microsoft will not allow for some reason does anybody no of a work around or an alternate solution.

The reason it is a protected document is that we have about 200 companies with different directors and we dont want people to be able to edit the headers or footers when sending mail merges out.

Comment: I can't really think of an easy solution there. You may create macro which unprotects a protected template, creates the final one and immediately converts it to pdf, however that probably will be quite a complicated macro if you want it to be tamper-proof. Considering also size of your company, I'd really suggest to buy a professional reporting tool, instead of Word's mail merge.

Comment: An alternative is Word variables (more precisely, "document properties"). I've tested: macros can update them in a protected document.